# how to add radio button in front end customer registration form and store it into database

Tags: radio-button, magento-1.9

kindly help me, how to add radion button in magento 1.9  in customer registration form and store it into database

```
          <div class="field">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="radio" name="login_reference"  value="customer_login" title="<?php echo $this->__('Customer Login') ?>" class="radio" checked />
                             <label for="login_reference"><?php echo $this->__('Customer Login') ?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="field">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="radio" name="login_reference"  value="store_user_login" title="<?php echo $this->__('Store User Login') ?>" class="radio" />
                             <label for="login_reference"><?php echo $this->__('Store User Login') ?></label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

i just created like this.how to save that value into database...

Answer (score 0):

You have overwrite customer controller and create one field in customer table as a login_reference .

you have to overwrite customer controller Accountcontroller.php file  using below code in config.xml within  Tag.

```
 <routers>
     <customer>
        <args>
          <modules>
              <companyname_modulename before="Mage_Customer">New_Mage_Customer</companyname_modulename>
           </modules>
        </args>
    </customer> 
</routers>
```

after that you have to create a function createPostAction() and set your field value in it.you can pass 0 or 1 value for save login_reference field.